# Why are my App tests not being recognized by Django tests?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, python-unittest, django-tests

### Background:

I have the following django project setup:

```
>TopLevel:
>  - App1:
>      * models.py
>      * forms.py
>      * views.py
>      * __init__.py
>      * Tests/
>        * __init__.py
>        * test_simple.py
```

Here is the code in test_simple.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_basic_addition(self):
        """
        Tests that 1 + 1 always equals 2.
        """
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 2)
```

Now, when I run:

```
> python manage.py test app1
```

I get the following output:

```
>Creating test database for alias 'default'...
>
>----------------------------------------------------------------------
>Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
>OK
>Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

But, if I instead use the following project structure:

```
>TopLevel:
>  - App1:
>      * models.py
>      * forms.py
>      * views.py
>      * __init__.py
>      * tests.py
```

Where tests.py has the following code:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_basic_addition(self):
        """
        Tests that 1 + 1 always equals 2.
        """
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 2)
```

Now, when I run:

```
> python manage.py test app1
```

I get:

```
>Creating test database for alias 'default'...
>.
>----------------------------------------------------------------------
>Ran 1 test in 0.002s
>
>OK
>Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

### Question:

Why does Django not recognize my Tests directory && why won't any tests listed inside Tests/ be picked up by Django's unittest structure to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to have a good sleep and don't even think about test discovery is to use [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It has a lot features, one of it is [automatic tests discovery](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html).

There is package called [django_nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) that will help you to integrate your django project with nose:

> Features
>
> All the goodness of nose in your Django tests, like...
>
> - ...
> - Obviating the need to import all your tests into `tests/__init__.py`. This not only saves busy-work but also eliminates the possibility of accidentally shadowing test classes.
> - ...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You will require to change your `Tests` to `tests` and import every test to `tests/__init__.py` up until django 1.5 AFAIK. Also there is a [test runner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-discover-runner) which will work the way unittest2 discovery work. This functionality has been integrated into django1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [running tests in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)

> Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named “test*.py” under the current working directory.